# Volatile happens-before clarification/misunderstanding?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile, java-memory-model

"A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of that field."

So I know that volatile field can be used as synchronization in order to guarantee that that all the information that thread 1 has before writing to volatile field is going to be visible to thread 2 after reading that volatile.

But what about subsequent writes? Is the behavior the same?
Any help appreciated, can't find anything about it in the official docs.

Examples:

```
### Write -> Read

#Thread1 (Write)
xxx = "anyValue" - any variable with value before volatile
boolean volatile b = true

#Thread2 (Read)
if (b) { -> here we read volatile value
 print(xxx) -> guaranteed visibility of 'xxx' 100%, will print 100% "anyValue"
}

### Write -> Write

#Thread1 (Write)
xxx = "anyValue" - any variable with value before volatile
boolean volatile b = true;

#Thread2 (Write)
b = false; -> here we write to volatile value
print(xxx); -> guaranteed visibility of 'xxx'???, what will be printed?
```

Comment: I've added some examples, maybe it can clarify what i am talking about, so u can provide some more precise answer. But anyway thank you for the answer )

Comment: 'xxx' is not boolean value, it is just any object that was changes or set in the Thread1, and i am interested if writing to the same volatile variable will provide access to this data for another Thread2. In case of reading it is 100%, but nothing about subsequent writes :(

Comment: you are not correct, when you are reading volatile field all the data that was accessible to the writer thread becomes accessible to the reader thread: http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html

Comment: *"[I] can't find anything about it in the official docs."* -  It is all specified in Chapter 17 of the JLS.  Yes, it is not easy to read ... but if you are going to write code that depends on `volatile` for synchronization, then you need to understand this stuff.  And conversely, if you can't understand what the JLS says you shouldn't be attempting to do your synchronization this way.  (Use the higher level concurrency primitives.  In the vast majority of use-cases, "lock free" synchronization is unnecessary.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I’ve read it once more and found same blocks of text. A write to a volatile variable v (§8.3.1.4) synchronizes-with all subsequent reads of v by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order). And this: A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of that field. So no info about subsequent writes... maybe i m just blind(

Comment: Well ... it doesn't mention subsequent writes by thread A because subsequent writes  have no associated guarantees.  The JMM spec is all about what >is< guaranteed.  It doesn't (and doesn't need to) enumerate the infinite set of things that are not guaranteed. If something is not *stated* as guaranteed then it is not guaranteed.

Comment: Like I said, the spec is not easy to read ... but all of the information is there.  And if *reasoning* about what is stated (and not stated) in the spec is too difficult for you, you shouldn't be attempting to do clever things with `volatile`.   IMO.

Comment: Maybe you are right. And I am still not ready for such things. But anyway thanks a lot for clarifying the correct answer to my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give a bit more comprehensive answer by building up the happens-before relation out of its basic orders:

1. synchronization order: this is the total order of all synchronization actions. Since a volatile write is a synchronization action, the 2 volatile writes to the same or different variables are part of the synchronization order. The synchronization order will even order e.g. the lock of A and the volatile read of B because it is a total order.
2. synchronizes-with order. This is a partial order that only orders certain synchronization actions. For example, the release of a lock with all subsequent acquires of that same lock and the write of a volatile variable and all subsequent reads of that variable. So 2 volatile writes to different or the same variables are not ordered by the synchronizes-with order.
3. program order: in simple terms, it is the order as specified by the program code. In your case, the 2 volatiles writes are not ordered by program order since they are issued by different threads.

Now we get to the last step: the happens-before relation which is an order. It is the transitive closure of the union of the program order and the synchronizes-with order.

So even though the 2 volatile writes are part of the synchronization order, they are not part of the synchronizes-with order, and as a consequence, they are not part of the happens-before order. So they don't induce any happens-before edges.